# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class ImageView

Tags: java, android

I am just tryna make a small android java xml app that counts the score of a game and it gives my this error "Error inflating class ImageView" .. anyone knows a solution ?

I actually searched and ppl said add this : android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
and it did nothing actually

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="417dp"
        android:layout_height="732dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/lebronjames" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/teamAScore3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/teamA"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/teamA"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/teamA" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="480dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="#FF9800"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.098" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/teamA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Team A"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/divider"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/teamB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Team B"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/teamA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.339"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/divider"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/teamA" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/teamBScore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/teamAScore3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/teamB"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/teamB"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/teamAScore3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/points2ButtonB"
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="+2 points"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.882"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/points2ButtonA"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/points2ButtonA" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/points2ButtonA"
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="+2 points"
        android:onClick="twoPointerA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/teamAScore3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/teamAScore3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/teamAScore3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/freeShotButtonA"
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Free shot"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/point3ButtonA"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/point3ButtonA" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/freeShotButtonB"
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:text="Free shot"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/point3ButtonB"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/freeShotButtonA" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/point3ButtonB"
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="+3 points"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.882"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/point3ButtonA"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/point3ButtonA" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/point3ButtonA"
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="+3 points"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/points2ButtonA"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/points2ButtonA" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/resetButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="reset"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.basketballscore/com.example.basketballscore.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML
>   file line #11: Error inflating class ImageView

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please share the full XML code to let us verify the issue.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the entire XML layout file.

Comment: can you tell us where is your image located in Drawable or Drawable-v24 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error inflating class ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698313/error-inflating-class-imageview)

Comment: its located at drawble-v24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[android:src](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:src)

> Sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView.It will display in
>   its original size. No automatic scaling .

Remove line

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/lebronjames"
```

and change with

```
android:src="@drawable/lebronjames"
```

and put your image in **Drawable** folder not **Drawable-v24**

Please read this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40624625/10182897) you will get the solution

Comment: can you tell us where you put your drawable file ?

Comment: under project>app>res>drawable

Answer (score 0):

this error is caused in end line of your xml code because you are using   `app:srcCompat="@drawable/lebronjames"`, change `srcCompat` property only to `src` or change ImageView to appCompatImageView

Comment: change ImageView to AppCompatImageView