# Could android:scaleType="fitXY" be causing Error: inflating class ImageView?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, imageview

I have seen in the Firebase Crashlytics dashboard that there is an user that had crashes in some of the app's activities in the OnCreate() method. I have seen that it is an error of the xml as the error is this one and it is related with the ImageView component:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line
> #24: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class ImageView

I have seen that the layouts of the activities that are causing these crashes have in common that in the ImageView there is an attribute that is

> android:scaleType="fitXY"

```
<ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:background="@drawable/img"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

So my question is, could that scaleType="fitXY" be causing all these crashes? Is it bad behaviour to use scaleType attribute in ImageViews then?

Thanks for the possible help

Comment: probably not, dig a bit deeper into the problem. it might not be related to the ImageView at all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57114852/20018861  in this other post the problem was because of the automatic scaling, why do you think that probably it is not a problem of scaling?

Comment: This is something to do with the kind of image you are using. Maybe it is too big or format not supported.

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez I am using hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi and xxxhdpi drawable folders, I am supporting all the devices format, I don't know what could be causing the crash then..

Comment: how big is the picture? like, width * height and bytes?

Comment: Same here I have no idea but with InflateException the cause is mostly the source of your image. You need to test and dig deeper.

Comment: @Shark the biggest image scaling (hdpi) is 550x480 and 4KB

Comment: Then posting this piece of XML isn't going to be enough to pinpoint the problem. How about posting the whole XML and the inflating code as well?